# How to use two adapter in single class

Tags: java, android

Right now I am doing chat functionalities.I am extending *ArrayAdapter*.With the help of these ArrayAdapter only, I can achieve many funtionalities in chat.So I can't change this ArrayAdapter.

But I have to use another one Adapter(BaseSwipeListAdapter.java) to achive swipe left(enable or not) functionlity.

**ChatActivity.java:**(using ChatAdapter inside this class):

```
 static public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatMessage>  {

    private final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
    private Activity context;
    String loggedUserId, loggedUserName;

    public ChatAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<ChatMessage> chatMessages) {
        super(context, resource, chatMessages);
        this.context = context;
        this.chatMessages = chatMessages;
    }

  }
```

I need to use this below code in ChatActivity.java to achieve my result.But I can't extend BaseSwipeListAdapter.Because I am already using ArrayAdapter.

```
    @Override
    public boolean getSwipEnableByPosition(int position) {
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**BaseSwipeListAdapter.java:**

```
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;


public abstract class BaseSwipListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public boolean getSwipEnableByPosition(int position){
        return true;
    }



}
```

**SwipeMenuAdapter.java: (Libarary class):**

```
public class SwipeMenuAdapter implements WrapperListAdapter,
        OnSwipeItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SwipeMenuLayout layout = null;

        if (mAdapter instanceof BaseSwipListAdapter) {

            boolean swipEnable = (((BaseSwipListAdapter) mAdapter).getSwipEnableByPosition(position));

            layout.setSwipEnable(swipEnable);   --->This line is used to enable and disable the swipe left in listview.I need to use this method
        }

        return layout;
    }
```

How to call this method setSwipEnable(swipEnable) in ChatActivity.class

I think it's not possible to use two adapter in single class.is there any alternate way to solve this issue.

Comment: I think you can do it by using interface, create one interface and extend swipe adapter in it and then implement this interface in your chat adapter ...

Comment: @Vickyexpert just now I tried to use interface.But it is not working

Comment: @Naruto please describe your requirement more.Do you want to use swipe menu listview ?

Comment: @JayShah If I use this method(getSwipEnableByPosition) means I have to extend BaseSwipeListAdapter.But its not possible.because I am already using ArrayAdapter.is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by if condition if listview size is greater than 0.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SwipeMenuLayout layout = null;

    if (mAdapter instanceof BaseSwipListAdapter) {

        boolean swipEnable = (((BaseSwipListAdapter) mAdapter).getSwipEnableByPosition(position));
        if( listviewsize > 0)
        layout.setSwipEnable(swipEnable);   --->This line is used to enable and disable the swipe left in listview.I need to use this method
        else
        layout.setSwipEnable(swipDisable);
    }

    return layout;
}
```

**you can check listviewsize by**

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listview.size();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.But I think you are not understood my question.How to call this method setSwipEnable(swipEnable)  in ChatActivity.class

Comment: did yu tried with singleton class or by using interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some modification in library for this.In your ChatMessage bean class you can take boolean variable for that you want to make swipe option to be enable or not.After that while setting adapter in SwipeMenuListView class some how you need to pass ArrayList of ChatMessage class there.After that where ever mTouchPosition code is written you can check for same position of ChatMessage class that swipe boolean is true or false.If swipe boolean is false then return false after  mTouchPosition assignment other wise handle all touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `ArrayAdapter` functionality from `BaseAdapter` is *not difficult*.

```
static public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter  { // or BaseSwipListAdapter if you like

    private final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
    private Activity context;
    private int layoutId;
    String loggedUserId, loggedUserName;

    public ChatAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<ChatMessage> chatMessages) {
        super(context, resource, chatMessages);
        this.context = context;
        layoutId = resource;
        this.chatMessages = chatMessages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return chatMessages == null ? 0 : chatMessages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return chatMessages == null ? null : chatMessages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        }

        // assuming the view is a TextView
        ((TextView) view).setText(getItem(position).toString());

        return view;
    }

    public void add(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addAll(Collection<? extends ChatMessage> col) {
        chatMessages.addAll(col);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        chatMessages.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```